# MySQL query sum result divide by number of row (Average)

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, syntax

I have following data in `MySQL` and i want to sum (total) and then divide by number for row.

Example:

I want to sum all number in `AcctSessionTime` column and divide that with number of items so in our case  `6+4+3+31=44` divide them with 4 number of row.

How do i craft query to do all in single query?

```
mysql> select AcctStartTime,AcctStopTime,AcctSessionTime 
       from radacct 
       where UserName='spatel' AND SipResponseCode='200';
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| AcctStartTime       | AcctStopTime        | AcctSessionTime |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2015-06-04 15:32:03 | 2015-06-04 15:32:09 |               6 |
| 2015-06-04 16:11:27 | 2015-06-04 16:11:31 |               4 |
| 2015-06-04 16:13:37 | 2015-06-04 16:13:40 |               3 |
| 2015-06-05 11:44:31 | 2015-06-05 11:45:02 |              31 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Notes:** above is example data we have actual data in thousands of rows.

Answer (score 5):

The calculation `SUM(RowData) / #Rows` is an Average of `RowData` - this is already supported natively as the `AVG` aggregate function:

```
select AVG(AcctSessionTime) 
from radacct 
where UserName='spatel' AND SipResponseCode='200';
```

You can also do grouped averages with a `GROUP BY` statement, if required

Comment: Wow!!! that was super duper easy!!! time to learn SQL. but you guys are so helpful so never tried to open book :(

Comment: Um, with 4.5k rep, you already know how SO appreciates it when you show what you've tried before you get stuck.

Comment: I earn all rep from `Linux OS` stuff  very less use of SQL, sometime stuck just ping here and get answer so never bother to learn!!..

Comment: That is experience in my head when I was read the question I start to group by, sum column and divide with count etc... :) upvote because I learn that I need to read documentation more carefully it can make life easier... GL

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> select sum(AcctSessionTime) div count(AcctSessionTime) as result from radacct where UserName='spatel' AND SipResponseCode='200';

| result |
+--------+
|     11 |
```

You can try this.

Comment: Your example works and is great when you have to do divide to a count(distinct something) for eg, otherwise an usual avg will do it. You can use '/' operator instead of DIV, because DIV truncates. Also a `ROUND` will be nice and a `NULLIF` may be required to prevent the division by zero. So the query will become `SELECT ROUND(SUM(AcctSessionTime) / NULLIF(COUNT(AcctSessionTime), 0), 2) AS result FROM radacct WHERE UserName='spatel' AND SipResponseCode='200';`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Select AVG(AcctSessionTime) from radacct where UserName='spatel' AND SipResponseCode='200';
```